# Understanding an example in Golan on pg.309

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

The example is given below:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1-How do we get the matrix $B$?

2- can not the diagonal elements be arranged as follows instead 2,2,3,3,3?

3- From where the 1 below number 3 in matrix B came?

Could anyone help me answer these questions, please?

Comment: It sounds like this is just meant as an example that you can check by calculation.  Presumably the explanation of how you would find $B$ and $P$ comes later.

Comment: No, it did not come later ... the chapter ends without saying why .... Golan usually do this @EricWofsey